# PhpStorm Symfony problems (not finding anything)

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

I have a strange problem with PhpStorm and Symfony plugin. After having worked fine for many months, suddenly it won't recognize any Symfony method. A simple `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` won't work, since PhpStorm says "Method getDoctrine() not found". Neither `$this->get("whatever")`.

What is the cause and how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE? It's a first thing to try in "suddenly cannot resolve method" cases.

Comment: yes, but nothing changed

Comment: Does your controller extend `AbstractController`?

Comment: A full listing of the controller class (including use statements) could be helpful. Perhaps the issue is just because of invalid parent class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by searching on the Internet.
Regarding this article:
https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/1266
PhpStorm doesn't like many projects opened in the same window, since it doesn't know where to find the references it needs because all the projects have the same structure.
In my opinion this is very horrible programmatically speaking, I hope that JetBrains will fix this!
Thanks everybody anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can comment above a Variable if you want in php.
PhpStorm will recognize it and link the classes.

For example:

```
/** @var Serializer $serializer */
$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
```

Comment: Telling PHPStorm what is returned from the container (for namespaced classes, at least) https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/01/28/2-files-that-your-symfony-application-misses/#why-phpstorm-doesn-t-quot-get-quot-it